# How to import fuse.js into a react native project, getting an error

Tags: react-native, npm, yarnpkg, fuse.js

I'm getting the error `Internal Error react-packager has encountered an internal error`

When i try to `import Fuse from 'fuse.js';` in one of my screens

I installed to my react-native project by `yarn add fuse.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this answer is a little late, but I hope it will help someone else in the future:

`import Fuse from 'fuse.js/src';`

That worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

In Feb 2020, this worked for me, RN 0.5.9 & fuse.js^3.4.6

```
import Fuse from 'fuse.js';
```